# Unable to click button with Selenium - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multi-factor-authentication

I'm having difficulty clicking on a button using selenium. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong

`self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Call Me ')]").click()`

EDIT:
So Think the problem is the the xpath according to
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/xpath-text-buy-now-is-working-but-not-containstext-buy-now

However, my new function is still not able to locate the element
`//button[contains(.,'Call Me')]`

Thanks for the help so far.

Below is the HTML code for the button I'm trying to get to.

```
<div id="auth_methods">

<fieldset data-device-index="phone1" class="">
<h2 class="medium-or-larger auth-method-header">
Choose an authentication method
</h2>

<div class="row-label push-label">
<input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Duo Push">
<span class="label factor-label">
<i class="icon-smartphone-check"></i>
Duo Push


<small class="recommended">
Recommended
</small>


</span>
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="positive auth-button"><!-- -->Send Me a Push </button>
</div>

<div class="row-label phone-label">
<input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Phone Call">
<span class="label factor-label">
<i class="icon-call-ringing" alt="" role="presentation"></i>
Call Me

</span>
<button tabindex="2" type="submit" class="positive auth-button"><!-- -->Call Me </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same trouble, and I tried this:

```
path =  'your xpath'
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
button.Click()
```

This work very well for me.